# $logs Container not created when enabling logging on Azure blob account

Tags: logging, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to enable logging so I can get hit/access counts for files within a specific container. I've gone into the portal, selected the storage account and under CONFIGURE, checked the READ REQUESTS under LOGGING for the BLOB and set the RETENTION to 0 days. However I am not seeing the $logs container automatically created in the blob [as stated here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343262.aspx). Is there some special trick?

I'm fairly certain this is what I should be doing to get this working, but can't figure out what's wrong. I'm simply trying to get hit counts on files accessed in the the blob so if there is another way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no special trick really :). You just have to wait out. Once you have enabled storage analytics properly, these containers and tables are created automatically by storage service when it needs to push some data there. Just ensure that you have configured it properly.

Is there a particular reason why you have set the rentention period as 0 days? Try setting it to 1 and see if that makes the difference.

**Update**

It is important to realize that when blob containers (or for that matter tables) are listed, the analytics blob container (and tables) are not returned in that listing. If you're using a client utility to view data in these containers/tables, please ensure that the tool supports storage analytics feature.

Comment: RE 0 days - The portal said if you leave it as zero, there is no retention schedule which I read to mean they will never be purged.

I did setup this logging about a week ago and I am certain files have been downloaded... but still nothing appears.

Comment: That's weird. I tried the same thing and I was able to see the $logs container created successfully. I was even able to see the entries in that container. How are you checking if the $logs container is being created?

Comment: Using bi the browser in the portal and Cloudberry's Azure explorer tool. Think I'll open a support ticket

Comment: One thing I should mention is that when you list blob containers in your storage account `$logs` container is not returned in that list. Can you check if Cloudberry's tool supports storage analytics? You may want to download Cerebrata's Azure Management Studio (http://www.cerebrata.com) as I know it supports storage analytics (I was part of Cerebrata team when we built this feature in the tool).

Comment: AH! I didn't realize that. Now I see in Cloudberry where it can display the logs. Thanks!